# Converting numeric bytes to character representation

Tags: ruby

I have the following numeric bytes that I would like to find out the character representation for, where/how do I do this?

```
239 187 191 104
```

Comment: What encoding are they in? Without knowing that, it's impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`chr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-chr) method on each of these:

```
[239, 187, 191, 104].map(&:chr)
#=> ["\xEF", "\xBB", "\xBF", "h"]


# tilde, the last printable character
126.chr
#=> "~"
```

I think starting 127 would be non-standard chars

Comment: Just a follow-up, "h" makes sense, but the others not - any idea how I can understand what they "mean"?

Comment: @Numbers I am sure it is some non-standart chars, but truly to say don't know yet how to understand it

Answer (score 1):

Use the method `chr` of fixnum. Like so:

239.chr
 => "\xEF"

If your input is a space separated string, you may use split and map:

```
"239 187 191 104".split.map(&:to_i).map(&:chr)
```